# If $E$ is compact and $f_n$ and $g_n$ are continuous for all $n$, is it true that the products $(f_ng_n)$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

If $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact and $f_n$ and $g_n$ are continuous for all $n$, and each converge uniformly on the set $E$ to $f$ and $g$ respectively, is it true that the products $(f_ng_n)$ converge uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

$\|f_{n}g_{n}-fg\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}\sup_{n}\|g_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}+\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}\|g_{n}-g\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}$. Note that $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}=\max_{x\in E}|f(x)|<\infty$.

Comment: Can you please explain what this means?

Comment: Essentially in this case the $L^{\infty}(E)$ norm is equivalent to that $\sup_{x\in E}|f(x)|$, do you know that uniform convergence $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ is another characterisation of saying that $\sup_{x\in E}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$?